# UIAutomation test fails after pushing new view controller (tuneup.js)

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I just started trying UIAutomation with tuneup.js. I can test my first window just fine, but the second window fails -- my app is still looking at the first window and sees e.g. the "Sign in with Facebook" button. I've tried adding delays but this didn't seem to help. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

```
#import "tuneup.js"

target = UIATarget.localTarget();
application = target.frontMostApp();

test("Test first-run view controller", function(app, target) {
 assertWindow({
              buttons : [
                         { name : "Sign in with Facebook"},
                         { name : "Create account"},
                         { name : "Login"},
                         { name : "Try"}
              ], 
              onPass: function(window) {

                var createAccountButton = window.buttons()["Create account"]
                createAccountButton.tap();
              }

 });

});

test("Test Sign-in screen", function(app, target) {
 assertWindow({
    buttons : [
              { name : "Sign up"}
        ]
 });

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found what was going on. I didn't realize it, but my sign-in screen has a scroll view containing its buttons. This code worked fine:

```
test("Test the account creation", function(app, target) {
 assertWindow({
              scrollViews: [
                    { buttons : [
                            {name :"Sign up"},
                            {name : "Terms and Conditions"}
                            ]

              }
                            ],
              onPass: function(window) {
                var signUpButton = window.scrollViews()[0].buttons()["Sign up"];
                signUpButton.tap()
              }
 });

 });
```

Comment: Just wondering if your script runs on a real device? a simulator? or none?

Comment: Hey @WendyMunmunWang, I ran the script on both devices and simulators if I remember correctly, but it's been a long time since I've looked at tuneup.js. Apple's deprecated the JS based UIAutomation and added a new Objective-C based UI Test feature.

Comment: @MaxBabriel Do you think it is possible to run without using any simulator or real device? I would like to get the test results just by reading logs

Comment: @WendyMunmunWang No I'm pretty sure you need to run it on a simulator or device. Something has to run the code. It is possible to have tests record results to a file that you can read